# FreeBSD ports: Set make defines not exposed as Options

Tags: freebsd

In FreeBSD, when you do make config, lots of ports have options that can be set. These options are saved so that when you update the port, they are used again.

Some ports have additional items that are checked for in the Makefile, but not exposed as a configure option. For example, the maildrop port has the MAILDROP_TRUSTED_USERS checked with the following if statement in the Makefile:

```
.if defined(MAILDROP_TRUSTED_USERS)
   CONFIGURE_ARGS+=        --enable-trusted-users="${MAILDROP_TRUSTED_USERS}"
.endif
```

I'm having a brain fart, where can I set MAILDROP_TRUSTED_USERS so that it will be used if the  port get updated later by postmaster? For this install I defined it manually, but if I use postmaster to update a port that forces this port to update, I'd like the value be set for the build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `/etc/make.conf`.

Comment: Thank you, I search for something like that for 1/2 hour. I was only able to the options page.